# Ground state bleach in transient absorption with at least 3 states

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, physical-chemistry, spectroscopy

The ground state (GS) bleach (B) is usually described by "less absorption due to depletion of electrons in the ground state". See [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2744833/).

But the bleaching should also occur when there are many excited states, right? In a two level system there is no difference in saying that, but let's assume the following:
A sample with molecules with one GS and two higher levels, that have slightly different energies, so I can observe them at different probe wavelengths. Now I excite the levels, and one states decays back to the GS faster than the other. Then I will see two different dynamics of GSB recovery, depending on my probe wavelength. (?)

Following the definition at the top, it only depends on the depletion of the GS. Then I would not see GSB recovery dynamics that depend on the probe wavelength.

So is it possible to see different GSB dynamics in different spectral regions? (Excluding other effects that overlap as excited state absorption or stimulated emission)